# multiple tables mapping entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping, code-first

I have 3 Entities Roles, Modules and Permissions and I am following code first approach using EF 6

**Roles** has **RoleID** , **Modules** has **ModuleID** and **Permissions** has **PermissionID** as Keys.

Now I want Map these 3 ID values to another mapping table RoleAccess on creating **Role**

I am able to map entity to with ICollection property and the same is not working for the above scenario.

help me out with code suggestions...

The configuration i am trying add is below..

'this is the mapping configuration i am trying  `this.ToTable("Roles");
            //this.HasKey(c => c.Id)
            //   .HasMany(c => c.Permissions)
            //   .WithRequired()
            //   .HasForeignKey(c => new { c.SubModuleId, c.EntitlementTypeId });

```
        this.HasMany(a => new[] {a.SubModules,a.EntitlementTypes})
            .WithMany(b => b.Roles)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("Permissions");
                mc.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                mc.MapRightKey(new[] { "SubModuleId", "EntitlementTypeId" });
            });`'
```

Comment: please share your code you have tried